# Javascript given an array with html tag names and string return html without dom

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Javascript string to html without dom. This is for a content management system that stores content data like this.

Given an array:

`var arr = [['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'];`

show output:

`<u><i>some paragraph</i></u>`

```
var getTag = function(tag, str){
  var text = "";
  switch (tag) {
    case "":
      text = `<p>${str}</p>`;
      break;
    case "italics":
      text = `<i>${str}<i>`;
      break;
    case "underline":
      text = `<u>${str}</u>`;
      break;
    case "strikethrough":
      text = `<s>${str}</s>`;
      break;
    case "bold":
      text = `<b>${str}</b>`;
      break;
    default:
      text = ``;
  }
  return text;
};

arr[0].map((e) => {
  console.log( getTag(e, arr[1]) );
});
```

expected:

```
<u><i>some paragraph</i></u>
```

actual:

```
<u>some paragraph</u>
<i>some paragraph</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to obtain the desired result where, for each reduce iteration, the current `element` of that iteration is wrapped around the accumulated result as shown below.

To obtain the required wrapping order, the `elements` array would first be reversed via a call to [`Array#reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```js
var arr = [['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'];

/* Extract element and content data from arr */
const [elements, text] = arr;

/* Reduce elements to the result string to wrap result with each 
element iterated */
const result = elements.reverse().reduce((acc, element) => {

  switch(element) {
    case 'underline':
      return `<u>${acc}</u>`;
    case 'italics':
      return `<i>${acc}</i>`;
    case 'strikethrough':
      return `<s>${acc}</s>`;
    case 'bold':
      return `<b>${acc}</b>`;
  }
  
  return acc;

}, text);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: MAybe addition to this answer could be that we can extract `switch` block to a function say `getTags` or `getMarkup` so that it maybe used independently

Comment: @DacreDenny your updated part is already given as answer by other user [`cjc's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932479/9624435) we can refer to that answer instead,

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `tagMap object` which holds the start and end tags, first loop through the tag array to get starting tags, than add text and than loop on reversed tag to get ending tags.

```js
let tagsMap = {
  "": { start: "<p>", end: "</p>" },
  "italics": { start: "<i>", end: "</i>" },
  "underline": { start: "<u>", end: "</u>" },
  "strikethrough": { start: "<s>", end: "</s>"},
  "b": { start: "<b>", end: "</b>"}
}
let arr = [['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'];

let getTag = ([tags,text]) => {
  let final = ""
  
  // adding starting tags
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    final += tagsMap[tag] && tagsMap[tag].start || ''
  })
  
  // adding text
  final += text;
  
  // adding ending tags
  [...tags].reverse().forEach(tag => {
    final += tagsMap[tag] && tagsMap[tag].end || ''
  })
  return final
}

console.log(getTag(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is going from the last to the first element on the list of elements you are replacing.

Like:

```js
var arr = [
  ['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'
];

var tags = {
  'underline': 'u',
  'italics': 'i',
};


var formatted = arr[0].reverse().reduce((description, tag) => {
  return `<${tags[tag]}>${description}</${tags[tag]}`;
}, arr[1]);

console.log(formatted);
```

1. Creates a hash with the supported tags
2. Reverse to process from last to first element of tags
3. Apply a reduce to process over the paragraph

PS: A check inside of the callback of reduce is required in case a tag is not defined on the tags hash.

Comment: You can create running snippet on SO [`create a snippet on SO`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

By using [reduce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-reduce-method/) with an initial value you can do what you are looking for. Note: because of the order of arguments for `reduce` you have to switch the order of the arguments for the function you provided (I did not change the actual contents of the function).

**Edit:**
To preserve the order, you need to use [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight).

```js
var arr = [['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'];

var getTag = function(str, tag){
  var text = "";
  switch (tag) {
    case "":
      text = `<p>${str}</p>`;
      break;
    case "italics":
      text = `<i>${str}<i>`;
      break;
    case "underline":
      text = `<u>${str}</u>`;
      break;
    case "strikethrough":
      text = `<s>${str}</s>`;
      break;
    case "bold":
      text = `<b>${str}</b>`;
      break;
    default:
      text = ``;
  }
  return text;
};

var result = arr[0].reduceRight(getTag,arr[1])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: desired output `<u><i>some paragraph</i></u>` you need to reverse tags

Comment: switched to using reduceRight to preserve the order

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make `getTag` recursive, only returning the text when there are no more modifiers to apply:

```js
var arr = [['underline', 'italics'], 'some paragraph'];

var getTag = function(arr){
  if (!arr[0].length) return arr[1];
  switch (arr[0].shift()) {
    case "":
      text = '<p>' + getTag(arr) + '</p>';
      break;
    case "italics":
      text = '<i>' + getTag(arr) + '</i>';
      break;
    case "underline":
      text = '<u>' + getTag(arr) + '</u>';
      break;
    case "strikethrough":
      text = '<s>' + getTag(arr) + '</s>';
      break;
    case "bold":
      text = '<b>' + getTag(arr) + '</b>';
      break;
    default:
      text = '';
      break;
  }
  return text;
};

console.log(getTag(arr));
```

Comment: cool, i will not consider it simple but yes still an alternate way to get the things done, reason i don't consider it simple is my personal opinion whenever anything is possible with simple iteration i don't prefer recursion,

Comment: @CodeManiac agree to disagree on that. I think this is a problem that calls for a recursive solution as we are putting something inside something which is generated the same way. Anyway, I'm going to get my Sportsmanship badge by returning the favour...